# When using weight with LinearLayout and 3 buttons, middle button is a bit low

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout, inside a Dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text=""
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:enabled="false"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rView"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okbutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/markall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkall"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the drawable I am using as background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="50dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="@color/botones"
    />
<stroke
    android:width="0dp"
    android:color="#878787"
    />
```

Inside the LinearLayout there are 3 buttons, as you can see. Each of them should use the same amount of space in the linear layout, and they in fact do, but the central button (markall) is not aligned with the others, is a bit low, like 5 dp or something like that. I don't know why is this happening, and how to solve it.

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: i think its working fine look screenshot : http://prntscr.com/gnf4vn

Comment: Yeah, I know it should work, but was not working for me.

Comment: You can't use _wrap_content_ because you'r using weight

Comment: Well, yeah, thats the theory...but it solved it...

Comment: Try removing weightSum from  LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Change buttons width "match_parent".

Comment: You can't use `match_parent` because OP is using `weight`

Comment: Changed it to wrap_content and it was solved. Thank you, you put me in the right path.

Comment: @Fustigador I Checked it, change your textSize and try

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

Set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to the `Button` .

And set `android:gravity="center"` to `Button` text .

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rView"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okbutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/markall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/checkall"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try either changing the android:layout_height="match_parent" to "wrap_content",
OR
each buttons height to "match_parent"